# How to get data from the html input after the user has pressed enter or clicked elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Js has a built-in function that allows you to retrieve data from an input when a user enters something into it: `input.addEventListener("input", myFunction())`.
But it does not suit me, because it is executed every time the user enters at least one character. Instead, I need an approach in which the function would be called only when the user typed something and then pressed enter or clicked on a page in different place.

Comment: [The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following methods for this:

1. use `onblur` for the input elements. This will trigger once the user clicks anywhere outside of that input box.
2. use `onsubmit` for the form. This will trigger when the user presses enter or submits the form in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `focusout` event which fires when an element is about to lose focus and for the enter key you could check the `event.key` within the `keypress` event which is fired when a key that produces a character value is pressed down. like so:

```
input.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
   if (e.key === 'Enter') {
     // code for enter
   }
});
```

**focusout**  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event

**keypress** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event